# npm install gives ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, cmd, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot and following [This Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=WhEas9UItHs)  but when I run

```
npm i discord.js
```

I get the following error response

[image: The code and its response]

Answer (score 1):

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '`c:\Users\dmlai\package.json'

If you inspect the `ENOENT` error. It says `package.json` doesn't exist.

Any dependency you add to a node project, will be added to the `dependencies:{}` of `package.json`. Since there is no `package.json` in the folder, it errors.

This might happen, if you issue `npm i discord` on a folder that wasn't initiallized as a node project.

So, to solve this.

1. Initialize the folder by

   `npm init`
2. This would create a `package.json` and would prompt you for further details.
   Complete the `package name`, `version` and other details.
3. Install `discord.js`

   `npm i discord.js`

You can now see that `discord.js` gets added to the `dependencies:{}` section of `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it created `node_modules` directory. Lib should be there. To avoid warnings like in your screenshot, first initialize `package.json` config by typing `npm init`.

Edit: Please next time paste output from your console to post instead of linking url to image. Let's make sure your question will stay clear. Screenshot from external source can be taken down.

Comment: Thank you @Kamil although it looked like it worked in the file explorer after typing the command I got what I believe is the same thing